# Доступ к ячейке таблицы

Tags: javascript, html

есть таблица, внутри `<td>` находится числовое значение, как до него добраться через javascript?

Comment: var allTD = [getElementsByTagName][1]("td"); + `element.innerHTML`

[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName

Comment: Прошу прощения, но мало что понял с вашего комментария, что такое element?

Comment: Всё ответы [тут][1].

[1]: http://learn.javascript.ru/#book-toc-42

Answer (score 2):

Вот запустите и посмотрите:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");//возвращает массив всех <td>
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  alert(tds[i].innerHTML);//выводим числовое значение каждого <td>
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, скажите, а как отследить номер ячейки при клике на нее? Нужно что бы при клике на ячейку, она  выдавала свой порядковый номер.

Comment: <td onclick="alert(this.innerHTML);">

Comment: Столкнулся с очередной проблемой, в любом случае клик выдает undefined, не подскажете в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: без html не подскажу